# User custom meta delete by serialised key value

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to delete the custom user meta values but having no luck.

If I have just, say a value of 479 against a key of saved_properties, this I can do with simple delete_user_meta($user_id,'saved_properties','479');

But how if at all possible can I do the same if the values are serialized

```
a:2:{s:6:"propID";i:479;s:6:"rating";i:2;}
```

Basically deleting or updating by the propID.

Is it possible and if so, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same. WP's _meta functions handle serialisation for you.

Comment: As you rightly point out, WP handles the  inputting of arrays (serializes) on saving, so, Unfortunately its not as simple as that as the meta_value is an array, so deleting the meta would need to be based on one array key matching with the argument.. eg delete from user meta where array key propID = 479.
I managed to figure it out now, by looping through the array "saved_properties" and used unset to remove the match